# Async queue - only process last message

Tags: java, asynchronous, queue

```
public void updatePrice(Price update){
   sendPriceUpdate(update); //takes a long time
}
```

I would like to structure a class which will perform the above except whilst the sendPriceUpdate call is still running it will wait and queue up the pending updates. Once the call returns it will send the last update (and discard the other updates). i.e. wait for the send call to return then send the last pending price update.

Whats the appropriate data structure to use?

Comment: you tagged it as "queue", i guess you know appropriate data structure already.

Comment: The thing is I'm not sure if a queue is correct as I only want the last update..dont really need to store more than one item in the queue.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is that updates already know this and only get "delta" data, that is, data that has changed or only differences. If this is not possible, then you have no choice than rollback latest update. For this you need to store previous update so you can undo it and push the new update. Something like this should work:

```
public class Updater
{
    private static Price prevUpdate = null;

    public static synchronized void updatePrice(Price update)
    {
        if (prevUpdate != null)
        {
            rollbackUpdate(prevUpdate);
        }
        sendPriceUpdate(update); //takes a long time        
        prevUpdate = update;
    }
}
```

I've changed this to `static` because I don't think you need to instance an object of this class. Looks like a static service to me. If I'm wrong (for example different threads want to use different Updaters, and thus keep track of different updates), please change it.

This is thread-safe, but if `sendPriceUpdate()` takes a long time, it can lock a lot of threads on the `updatePrice()` method. Also this doesn't consider any exceptions being thrown, you should take this into account.

As I said in the comments, IMHO this is a (very?) bad solution, but it's the only one if you have no idea which is last or when the last will arrive. A software redesign might solve this situation, or solve it in a higher level (before calling `updatePrice()`)

Comment: Thats not going to work as it will process all the price updates...I only ever want to process the latest price update.

Comment: Huh? You said: "I would like to structure a class which will perform the above except whilst the sendPriceUpdate call is still running it will wait and queue up the pending updates". Queuing is not processing only the last one. Please clarify yourself.

Comment: Why are you quoting me and not even including the full paragraph?? The next sentence clearly says discard everything but the last update.

Comment: Ok I see, so how do you define "last"? "Last" in which context/domain? If so, why even queue the other updates if they're not going to be used? Just wait for "last" (whatever this means) and process it.

Comment: What would you recommend instead? Storing the last known update and then checking if it is different once the call returns?

Comment: I looked it up in the dictionary for you: Coming after all others in time or order; final: "they caught the last bus".

Comment: ... so when is the final? Or worded in another way, so you can understand what I'm asking: how to know if there are any more updates coming?

Comment: Are you being serious? Last means the one which arrived latest. What else could it possibly mean?!

Comment: lol...I see how you can tell the quality of my software design from 2 lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use the Active-Object pattern - you should associate a queue (AKA Activation-queue or operations queue) to your object. I will first explain how to solve without discarding, and then explain how I think discarding should be handled.
The main idea is as follows: 
A. Your object will have field of a queue  - Let's say of a generic type of Queue (with generic argument of PriceOperation) 
B. PriceOperation will hold a method object (java.lang.reflect.method) , the target object for invocation -let's PriceManager (which has the updatePrice method) , and parameters (let's say for update it should be the Price) 
C. sendPriceUpdate will enqueue and object of PriceOperation, with a method object of "update" (let's say Price has such a method), or of the method you would have activated in a case of Synchronous invocation 
D. The thread that is associated with the object will wait on the queue, and when the queue is not empty, it will dequeue a PriceOperation object, and invoke the method on the target object (whether if this is PriceManager or something else) with the relevant parameter (the Price object) 
E. This way, you will be able to keep a queue of pending updates, and still work asynchronously with your PriceManager 
F. I just noticed that you're interested to discard the last updates - if this the case, then you should propably use a priority queue, and not a queue, and based the priority sorting on timestamp, in such a way that PriceOperation that was created the most recently will be handled. You will need to synchronize this queue between the proceducer (the PriceManager) and the consumer (the thread).